# Docker connection refused hanging Django

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

When I run my container, it just hangs on the next line and if I write

> curl http://0.0.0.0:8000/

I get

> Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8000: Connection refuse

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6.1

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "dockerizing/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

I also tried doing it through a docker-compose.yml file and again nothing happens, I´ve searched a lot and haven´t found a solution, this is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: app1
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

By the way, if I run docker ps with myapp image I get this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
e9633657f060        app1                "python3 dockerizi..."   5 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds                            friendly_dijkstra
```

When I deploy the service with the django-compose.yml and `docker ps` I get this:

```
`MacBook-Pro-de-Jesus:docker-django Almaral$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
13677a71d9d5        app1:latest        "python3 dockerizin..."   15 seconds ago      Up 11 seconds                           getstartedlab_web.1.cq3zqmpfsii5g6m5r9qsnmtb1
c6693118ef70        app1:latest        "python3 dockerizin..."   16 seconds ago      Up 12 seconds                           getstartedlab_web.4.r472oh80s4zd1yymj447f1df6
f3822e47970b        app1:latest        "python3 dockerizin..."   16 seconds ago      Up 12 seconds                           getstartedlab_web.2.lkp43v9h30esjohcnf3pe31hi
f66a4038ebdf        app1:latest        "python3 dockerizin..."   16 seconds ago      Up 12 seconds                           getstartedlab_web.5.xxu01ruebd84tnlxmoymsu0vo
e3d31c419c11        app1:latest        "python3 dockerizin..."   16 seconds ago      Up 13 seconds                           getstartedlab_web.3.uqswgirmg22sjnekzmf5b4xo7`
```

Comment: What OS are you running docker on?

Comment: try `curl http://localhost:8000` and show us the result

Comment: It´s macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Comment: This is the result for `curl http://localhost:8000`

curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8000: Connection refused

Comment: You should have `0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp` in the output of your `docker ps`. However your config seems ok. Try removing services, and start from scratch. (try `docker-compose down` to remove containers, and `docker service ls`)

Comment: I removed everything, images, containers, services, and started again, but the same happens

Comment: `CMD ["python", "dockerizing/manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]` instead of `python3`

Comment: Tried that, not working, also tried changing python to another version, if I just run `python3 dockerizing/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` without the docker image it works as expected

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `docker ps` output shows nothing in the PORTS column. That means that there's no port forwarding from the host to the container.

```
[...]     STATUS          PORTS                     NAMES
[...]     Up 5 seconds                              friendly_dijkstra
```

If you use the command `docker run` to run your container, you should explicitly specify port number both on host and on the container using the command option `-p hostPort:containerPort`

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 app1
```

Now, running `docker ps` should show port forwarding.

```
[...]     STATUS          PORTS                     NAMES
[...]     Up 5 seconds    0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp    friendly_dijkstra
```

If you are using `docker-compose` to start your containers, the host and container ports are already configured in your docker-compose.yml file, so you don't need a command line option.

```
docker-compose up web
```

To use docker compose, you have to install it on the host.
It's a python module, so you can install it with pip `pip install docker-compose`

Comment: Thanks this is working now!!, but it just works for the container by itself, it doesn´t work using the service with the docker-compose.yml

Comment: For those who have the same problem, I had to restart the mac and the docker compose worked, I think this is a docker bug

Answer (score 0):

Into your docker-compose config file, modify your port redirection from: `8000:8000` to `127.0.0.1:8000:8000`

Comment: Did that, nothing changes :(

Comment: Ok ! Try to remove your networks settings into your docker-compose config file (`networks: webnet` , etc)

Then add the port redirection modification. 

Restart your service: 
`docker-compose stop && docker-compose rm -f && docker-compose up -d`

Then post your `docker ps` result.

Comment: I updated the question with what I get when I run `docker ps`